# How to allow any IP in docker mongodb container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am developing an application with docker MongoDB. I can connect with the localhost but cannot connect with the public IP/any IP. mongod.cfg file can be found locally installed(pc/server) but I couldn't find the mongod.cfg file in docker container exec mode.

Note: My application is not running on docker only the MongoDB is running in docker.

Comment: As you added `docker-compose` tag in your question, did you run `mongodb` via `docker-compose`? Which ports do you open via `docker`?

Comment: Yes I run the mongodb via docker-compose and I open the default mongodb port(27017)

Comment: MongoDB's config file is in `/etc/`.